# ZEND framework & PHPUnit with ant having "unrecognized option --report"

Tags: zend-framework, ant, frameworks, phpunit

hi im doing a small application in the Zend Framework 1.8 Web Application Development book called storefront.

i have installed PHPUnit, version is PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann. and also i installed apache ant.

as my ebook i create a build folder and run ant command inside of this folder via CMD
(folder contain ant.properties,build.xml files)

i got a BUILD FAILED message when execute ant command, there is a message in test section "unrecognized option --report"

here is my build.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="StoreFront" default="build" basedir="../">

    <target name="getProps">
       <property file="${basedir}/build/ant.properties" />

       <condition property="script-suffix" value=".bat" else="">
            <os family="windows" />
       </condition>

       <echo message="---- Build Properties ----" />
       <echo message="" />

       <echo message="OS is ${os.name}" />
       <echo message="Basedir is ${basedir}" />
       <echo message="Property file is ${basedir}/build/ant.properties" />
       <echo message="Script-suffix is ${script-suffix}" />

       <echo message="" />
       <echo message="---- Storefront Properties ----" />
       <echo message="" />

       <echo message="Environment is ${environment}" />    

    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="getProps">
       <exec dir="${basedir}/tests" executable="phpunit${script-suffix}" failonerror="true">
          <arg line="--colors --report ${basedir}/build/report
             --log-xml ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.xml 
             --log-pmd ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.pmd.xml
             --log-metrics ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.metrics.xml
             --coverage-xml ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.coverage.xml 
             AllTests.php"/>
       </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="configure" depends="getProps">
       <copy file="${basedir}/application/application.php.dist"
             tofile="${basedir}/application/application.php" overwrite="true" />
       <replace file="${basedir}/application/application.php" token="@ENVIRONMENT@" value="${environment}" />
    </target>

    <target name="buildPreparation">
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/logs" />
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/report" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/build/logs" />
        <delete dir="${basedir}/build/report" />
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="buildPreparation,configure,test"/>
</project>
```

here is the message i got in cmd

```
   C:\wamp\www\storefront\build>ant
Buildfile: C:\wamp\www\storefront\build\build.xml

buildPreparation:

getProps:
     [echo] ---- Build Properties ----
     [echo]
     [echo] OS is Windows 7
     [echo] Basedir is C:\wamp\www\storefront
     [echo] Property file is C:\wamp\www\storefront/build/ant.properties
     [echo] Script-suffix is .bat
     [echo]
     [echo] ---- Storefront Properties ----
     [echo]
     [echo] Environment is development

configure:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\wamp\www\storefront\application

test:
     [exec] PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.
     [exec]
     [exec] unrecognized option --report

BUILD FAILED
C:\wamp\www\storefront\build\build.xml:28: exec returned: 1

Total time: 0 seconds

C:\wamp\www\storefront\build>phpunit --version
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

how can i fixed this one im just following steps in the book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--report` is not a valid command line switch in PHPUnit 3.6.

Please read the manual for valid options - http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions

Comment: thnks i cheanged it but please can u tell me how do i write these two commands in 3.6

--log-pmd ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.pmd.xml

--log-metrics ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.metrics.xml